# problema con agregar puntos a cadena

Tags: python, string

necesito realizar un programa el cuál pida al usuario que ingrese oraciones, y las agregue a la una lista, la primera letra siempre tiene que estar el mayúscula y debe terminar con un punto, si el usuario ingresó una cadena sin mayúsculas y puntos, debo agregarselas yo mismo.
Bien, pude agregar las mayúsculas y los puntos, lo que no estoy pudiendo hacer es cuándo el usuario ingresa una oración con un punto, ya que en ese caso debo convertir la cadena a mayúscula pero no agregarle un punto, probé con un for pero no me está saliendo, mi código es este:
obs(si el usuario ingresa el string ::q, termina la ejecución.

```
listavacia=[]
string=input("ingrese un string")
while string!="::q":
    string=input("Ingrese un string")
    cadena=string.capitalize()+"."
    cadena1=string.capitalize()
    listavacia.append(cadena)
print(listavacia)
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Me había olvidado, ahí la acepté, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es revisar si la primera letra de `string` es mayúscula con `isupper()` y revisar si termina en `.` con `endswith()`.

Para que el `while` termine al recibir `::q` puedes poner un `if` justo después de recibir el texto

No es necesario que tengas un `input` antes del `while` y otro adentro

Ejemplo completo:

```
listavacia = []
string = None

while True:
    string = input('Ingrese un string: ')
    
    if string == '::q':
        break
    
    if not string[0].isupper():
        string = string.capitalize()
    
    if not string.endswith('.'):
        string += '.'

    listavacia.append(string)
    
print(listavacia)
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
Ingrese un string:  agua
Ingrese un string:  Perro
Ingrese un string:  gato.
Ingrese un string:  ::q
['Agua.', 'Perro.', 'Gato.']
```